# FileNotFoundException on opening file from Application#onCreate

Tags: android, android-context, filenotfoundexception

This is my Application#onCreate method. I can access sessions.json from MainActivity but it throws FileNotFoundException when the same file is accessed from Application#onCreate method.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = this.openFileInput("sessions.json");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: where is path of this file?

Comment: In the internal application storage. I use the exact same line of code in the MainActivity and it works just fine.

Comment: It looks like file cannot be accessed from application context.

Comment: Seems strange. Try using an absolute path.
```String filePath = this.getFilesDir() + "/" + "sessions.json";

File yourFile = new File(filePath);```

Comment: For debugging purposes, you can also log ```this.getFilesDir()``` to ensure both are the same

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help. Same error :System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/me.itsrishi.exercisecounter/files/sessions.json (No such file or directory)

Comment: Even in MainActivity, when I changed this.openFileInput("sessions.json"); to getApplicationContext().openFileInput("sessions.json") , the same exception occured. So, I guess files can't be accessed from application context

Comment: And yes, in both activity and application context, getFilesDir() returned the same absolute path :
 activity: /data/user/0/me.itsrishi.exercisecounter/files 
 app:      /data/user/0/me.itsrishi.exercisecounter/files

Comment: @RishiRaj When you are creating this file?

Comment: The file already exists. I just read it

Comment: So, the bug disappeared on cleaning the project and building again. Weird